# Is there a way to force Jetpack Compose text to be shown?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I've been struggling with the following problem for a while. I achieved this (John's example):

[image: What I achieved]

But what I'm trying to do is to force the hour to **always** be shown directly after the text, and if the text is too long - overflow the text. So Jane Doe's example is perfect, same as Jack Doe's (but in Jack's case **that's all a dummy text**).

And I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong.

That's the piece of code I wrote:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
  .fillMaxWidth()
  .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 7.dp),
  verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
  Column {
    Row(
      verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
      horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
      // there's another Row printing the name
    }
    Spacer(Modifier.height(5.dp))
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {
      Row(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {
        Text(
          text = item.message,
          style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
          maxLines = 1,
          overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
      }
      Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {
        Circle() // that's my function which just shows the circle
        Text(
          text = dateString,
          style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
          maxLines = 1,
          modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'll be really grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: It feels like you should have one `Row()` with `Text()`, `Circle()`, and `Text()`, using modifiers to give the second `Text()` its natural width and giving all excess space to the first `Text()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for that reply - indeed, I've changed these two rows into one, but still I can't figure out how to do the second part. I was trying to use `Modifier.wrapContentWidth()` for the second text, but it still looks like the first text is being created first and thus takes all the available space. Could you, please, attach an example of what it should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Column {
        Message(message = "short message")
        Message(message = "short")
        Message(message = "very long message")
    }
}

@Composable
fun Message(message: String) {
    Text("John Doe")
    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
        Text(
            message,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1F, fill = false),
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1,
        )
        Text("8:35PM")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried something similar (with `maxLines = 1` parameter in the first `Text()`). Although it works fine when the text is long (longer than the row width), it always shows the time at the end of the row, even if the first `Text()` is very short, and that's not exactly what I was expecting. But thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Could you help me understand what it is want? Do you have a screenshot or mockup?

Comment: So the main assumptions were as follow:
1. The first text (a message) is always max 1 line long
2. If the message is longer than 1 line - it's overflowed (using ellipsis), and at the end of the line, the hour is shown
3. If the message is shorter than 1 line it's fully shown, and the hour is shown right after the message ends.
But the answer provided by @Francesc covered all of these 3 points

Comment: OK, I think I understand it a little better . I updated my answer

Comment: Wow, looks like that `fill = false` argument works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a `Layout` and using `IntrinsicWidth`. You can build on this example as it only uses 2 `Text`s for the children, but this should get you on the right path.

```
@Composable
fun MyRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(
        content = content,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        check(measurables.size == 2) { "This composable requires 2 children" }
        val first = measurables.first()
        val second = measurables[1]

        val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = 0,
            minHeight = 0,
        )
        val secondMeasurable = second.measure(looseConstraints)
        val maxHeight = secondMeasurable.height
        val availableWidth = constraints.maxWidth - secondMeasurable.width
        val maxWidth = first.maxIntrinsicWidth(maxHeight).coerceAtMost(availableWidth)
        val firstMeasurable = first.measure(
            Constraints(
                minWidth = maxWidth,
                maxWidth = maxWidth,
                minHeight = 0,
                maxHeight = maxHeight
            )
        )
        layout(
            constraints.maxWidth,
            maxHeight,
        ) {
            firstMeasurable.place(0, 0)
            secondMeasurable.place(maxWidth, 0)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun MyRowPreview() {
    SampleTheme {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.width(320.dp)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(
                    text = "John Doe",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                )
                MyRow(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Short Label",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp),
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        maxLines = 1,
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "8:35 PM",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp),
                    )
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                Text(
                    text = "John Doe",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                )
                MyRow(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Text(
                        text = "A long label that will require truncation goes here",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp),
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        maxLines = 1,
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "8:35 PM",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I really hoped there's an easier way, although it worked perfectly, so thanks a lot!